# Change URL of request in Middleware [Laravel 5.3]

Tags: laravel-5, request, middleware

I want to redirect my site to a subdomain depends of the browser language.

I mean if you go to

`example.com`

the middleware redirects to

`en.example.com`

If your browser language it's English.

So, how I change the $request in the middleware to redirect to the subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

In your middleware, access the browser language from,

```
$language = $request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
```

and the, do a

```
if($language == "en"){
    redirect()->route("path to your subdomain");
}else{
    //redirect to another sub domain
}
```

You will need some if conditions to decide the correct subdomain.

Comment: I don't want to define a route. I want to modify the $request to do a `return $next($request);` . If I do your answer I get a invalid route cuz I dont have that route declared.

Comment: What if you do `redirect()->to("subdomain".$request->url()")`?

Comment: I get `Call to a member function send() on null`